# Error java.lang.NullPointerException: Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm really new to programming in Android. I have the following error when I try to show a list after the update, delete or modify.

This is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.isc.dog, PID: 12520
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null 
    is null: method 
    kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, 
    parameter it
```

I know it could be related to this piece of code below.

```
 fun getDoges() : MutableLiveData<List<Dog>> {
    val listaFinal = MutableLiveData<List<Dog>>()
    firestore
        .collection("dogesApp")
        .document(codigoUsuario)
        .collection("misDoges")
        .addSnapshotListener { instantanea, e ->  //Le toma una foto/recupera los lugares del usuario
            if (e != null) {
                Log.d("Firestore","Error recuperando Mascotas", e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            if (instantanea !=null) {  //Hay datos en la recuperación
                val lista = ArrayList<Dog>()
                val doges= instantanea.documents
                doges.forEach {

                    val dog = it.toObject(Dog::class.java)

                    if (dog != null) {  //Si se pudo convertir a un lugar
                        lista.add(dog)
                    }
                }
                listaFinal.value = lista
            }
        }
    return listaFinal
}
```

I don't know how to fix this exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: None of the answers to that question are really helpful to understanding how to resolve this Kotlin issue. That is a very Java-focused question. Even if someone knows what causes an NPE in Java, if they’re new to Kotlin, it can be surprising to see one because of its null-safety features. If that question weren’t locked I would say it’s fine and someone could add some Kotlin examples of ways NPEs can still happen in Kotlin when interacting with Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code that is pointed to by the line number in the stack trace error, then the problem is that `instantanea.documents` must contain some null values, but you are assuming they are not null when you use `it.toObject`. You should change that to `it?.toObject`.

Also, this code isn’t going to accomplish anything because the Firestore API call is asynchronous. The outer function will return the empty `listaFinal` before the snapshot listener code is called, some time in the future. [This issue is explained in the answers here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57330766/506796)